# Dynamic Array - Android

Tags: android, arrays

How to create a dynamic array in this way:

```
// Just one example below:

String key = "0,1,2";
String valor0 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";
String valor1 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";
String valor2 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";

// A two-dimensional array, but without defining its size
String[][] valor = {};

// And then define its values with the first split []
valor[] = key.split(",");

// Now we define the values of the second [] with split also
valor[0][] = valor0.split(";");
valor[1][] = valor1.split(";");
valor[2][] = valor2.split(";");
```

So it would create the keys and after creating, set the values of the other array inside each key with the split. The size should be with the split, because this will be dynamic, will change constantly. In cases of just being a normal array, I know that split dynamically populates it without having to define the size, but I'd like to do the same with a two-dimensional array.

The example does not work, of course, it's just for show.

The array looks something like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string '7' (length=1)
      7 => string '8' (length=1)
      8 => string '9' (length=1)
      9 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string '7' (length=1)
      7 => string '8' (length=1)
      8 => string '9' (length=1)
      9 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string '7' (length=1)
      7 => string '8' (length=1)
      8 => string '9' (length=1)
      9 => string '0' (length=1)
```

I made this example in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know the number of rows. Ideally, you get this as an `int` somehow. With your given input you can do:

```
String key = "0,1,2";
int rows = key.split().length;
```

Now allocate the first dimension:

```
valor = new int[][rows];
```

Finally, add each row to the array:

```
valor[0] = valor0.split(";");
```

Note that you cannot use empty `[]` on the right hand side of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>`, i think it's more comfortable

[maybe something like this)))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soDiw.png)

Comment: I could do an example the same way I did, being two-dimensional